# Strange behaviour of realloc with certain values

Tags: c, realloc

I need to realloc an int array of initial dimension 5 with N values and fill them with the sum of previous values.
Everything works well if N <= 6 but if I put N == 7, program crash with this error:

> a.out: malloc.c:2403: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
>   (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
>   prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
>   0)' failed.

I do nothing special or strange, and I have no idea why I have this behaviour.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int * change(int * arr, int n)
{
  int * a, i, somma = 0;

  a = realloc(arr, n * sizeof(int));

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    somma += arr[i];

  for(int j = i; j < (5+n); j++) {
    a[j] = somma;
    somma += a[j];
  }

  return a;
}

int main()
{
  int N, i, *arr, *arr1;

  arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

  printf("give me 5 numbers\n");
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

  printf("give me N number to use in realloc\n");
  scanf("%d", &N);

  arr1 = change(arr, N);

  for(i = 0; i < (5+N); i++) {
    printf("%d\n", arr1[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I realloc in a different pointer to avoid problem.
Help are extremely usefull. Thanks

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve your code to get no warnings. Then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` ....) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: I use `clang -O0 -Wall -g` and compilation works well. I used also the debugger to understand the behaviour

Comment: Side note: `malloc & co.` functions can fail: check returned values **always**

Comment: @StoryTeller the coverage of the issue about using pointer after realloc could be of benefit to future readers.  The "M" in MCVE isn't to be taken literally (otherwise we are playing code golf), IMO this program is short enough to digest in one chunk and there is not a huge amount that could be stripped out

Comment: @M.M - And you are entitled to that opinion. No one is taking away your voice and forbidding you to up-vote. Others are entitled to theirs as well, and their down-votes don't make them "trolls". At this point it's a philosophical debate, and as comments aren't for extended discussion, let's agree to disagree on the merits of the code sample.

Comment: when calling any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: variable names should indicate 'content' or 'usage' (or better, both) .  variable names like 'a' and 'N'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the posted code contains 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 5.  Give 'magic' numbers meaningful names via `#define` or `enum` statements, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: This line: `a = realloc(arr, n * sizeof(int));` is NOT allocating (5+n)*sizeof(int) bytes, so the following loop is writing off the end of the array.  That is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest: `a = realloc(arr, (5+n) * sizeof(int));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
a = realloc(arr, n * sizeof(int));

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  somma += arr[i];
```

The `realloc` function invalidates the argument passed, `arr`. It causes undefined behaviour to use `arr` afterwards, as you do by writing `arr[i]`.

To fix this you could move the summation to before the `realloc` line.

---

Another problem is that the next loop writes out of bounds:

```
for(int j = i; j < (5+n); j++) {
    a[j] = somma;
```

You only allocated space for `n` entries but then you loop up to `5+n`.  (And in `main` you loop up to `5+N` too). Maybe you should realloc `(5+n)` entries instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

After you reallocated `arr` here

```
 a = realloc(arr, n * sizeof(int));
```

you may not use it any more like here:

```
 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   somma += arr[i];
```

but just use `a` instead,

Answer (score 2):

You call `realloc` to allocate `n` integer elements in your array. Then you loop over `n + 5`. Same in the `main` function, you loop over `N + 5` elements, when the new array only have `N` elements.

That of course leads to *undefined behavior* as you go out of bounds.